# Tcl: cd back to previous directory

Tags: tcl

On Unix, `cd -` can switch back to previous directory. I was wondering if there's a similar command in tcl interpreter can do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no directory stack in Tcl, and previous directory is not remembered anywhere.

[TclX](http://tclx.sourceforge.net/) provides `pushd` and `popd` commands for directory stack, but it does not modify `cd` command to put anything there. It can be done by command wrapping and renaming, but I wouldn't recommend it for something that can be used in a script (at least, don't override semantics of `cd -`).

Answer (score 4):

Tcl doesn't maintain a directory history/stack by default; you'd have to add one. You can do that in pure Tcl though:

```
rename cd real_cd
variable old_dir [pwd]
proc cd {directory} {
    variable old_dir
    if {$directory eq "-"} {
        set directory $old_dir
    }
    set old_dir [pwd]
    real_cd $directory
}
```

This is a very simple version that only remembers the last location, but everything else can be built on top in the same way.